# R Programming: Saving printed output of a for loop to a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, output

I've been messing around with coding in R and I've run into a little trouble. Here is my code:

```
# Pre-defined variables
rquote <- "R's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]

# Your solution here
result<-c()
for (v in chars) {
if (v=="r" | v=="R") {
} else if (v >= "u") {
break
} else {
next
}
result[v]<-v
}
result
```

I was hoping that result would contain all of the printed output the for loop created. It's supposed to be "R" followed by four "r's". However, I only end up with a vector that has "R" and "r" only (so only two of the five elements). Does anyone know how I can get the full vector?

Comment: Of course you have only 2 `R` and `r`. You overwrite `result[v]` every time you match one of them. See with `result <- c(result, v)`, even if it is a bad practice.

Comment: You should use some indentation cause it's hard to see if the conditions end where you want this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the characteristics of the intermediate values:

```
> str(chars)
 chr [1:40] "R" "'" "s" " " "i" "n" "t" "e" "r" "n" ...
```

I thought a while loop would be more in keeping with your apparent desire to stop processing when the character was a "u":

```
result<-c(); i=1
while ( chars[i] != "u") {
if (chars[i]=="r" | chars[i]=="R") {
result[i] <- chars[i]
} else { result[i] <-""}
 i=i+1
}
result
#------
[1] "R" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "r" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "r" ""  "" 
[19] ""  "r" "r" ""  ""
```